# Calculating determinant of $A^n$ given the matrix $A$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Find if $det(A)=det(A^n)$ for $n>1$.

How do I tackle questions like this, in general if the matrix $A$ is provided in the question?
Should I work out with the basic definition of a determinant, which I found very difficult to apply in any question?
I cannot of course go on to calculate the value of $det(A^n)$?

Comment: Do you know that $\det(A^n)=(\det A)^n$?

Comment: Yes, thankyou @MPW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determinant function is multiplicative, i.e. $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$. In particular, this means that $\det(A^n) = \det(A)^n$. So given a matrix $A$, just find its determinant and raise it to the given power.

For instance, let

$$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
6 & 2 \\
7 & 5
\end{matrix} \right]$$

Then $\det(A) = 6 \cdot 5 - 2 \cdot 7 = 16 = 2^4$. So if I asked you to find $\det(A^n)$ you could just tell me $16^n$ or $2^{4n}$, whichever fits your fancy.

In fact, I could even specify large $n$ and you might calculate it easily enough, if you're familiar enough with your powers of $2$ in this case. For instance, $\det(A^4) = 2^{16} = 65536$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ be matrices. Then it is well known that $\det$ is linear w.r.t matrix multiplication, i.e
$$\det(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})=\det(\mathbf{A})\det(\mathbf{B})$$
Therefore
$$\det(\mathbf{A}^n)=\det\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{A}\right)$$
$$=\prod_{i=1}^{n}\det(\mathbf{A})=(\det(\mathbf{A}))^n.$$